# How to stop multiple jQuery Ajax calls made after multiple times opening different modal windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Lets imagine that I have a page where all my projects are listed in the table:

ID | PROJECT-NAME | PROJECT-LINK

1 Project 1       | (BUTTON)

2 Project 2       | (BUTTON)

3 Project 3       | (BUTTON)

Now at the moment of clicking (BUTTON) for `Project 1` I'm running this JavaScript code:

```js
// on button click opening modal window
$(".modal-button").on('click', function () {
    let button = $(this);
    const id = button.attr('data-id');

    // calling backend to get details necessary for modal popup
    $.ajax({
      url: "/project?id=" + id,
      type: "get",
      success: function(response){
        if(!response.result){
          if(response.error === 'expired'){
            $('.expired').show();
          } else {
            alert(response.error);
          }
        }
        let url = response.url;
        let modal = document.getElementById("project-modal");
        let span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // showing modal popup
        $('.copied-text').hide();
        $('.expiration-changed').hide();
        $('#project-modal').show();

        // inserting link to disabled input field
        $("#link").val(url);
        $("#logo-link").val(response.project_url);
        $("#expiration-date").val(response.expiration_date);

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
          $('#project-modal').hide()
        };

        // adding close button
        $("#share-close-btn").on('click', function(){
          $('#project-modal').hide()
        });

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (event.target == modal) {
            $('#project-modal').hide()
          }
        };
      }
    });

    $("#date").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });

    // modal button to send new data
    $("#copy-btn").on('click', function(){
      $('#link').select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      this.focus();
      let img_url = $("#logo-link").val();
      let request_data = {"id": id, "img_url": img_url};
      $.ajax({
        url: "/projects",
        type: "post",
        contentType:"application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(request_data),
        success: function(response){
          if(!response.result){
            alert(response.error);
          }
        }
      });

      $('.expiration-changed').hide();
      $('.copied-text').show();

    });

  });
```

Now the JS code, it basically shows `$('#project-modal').show();` my hidden modal window (as it is initially with `style="disabled: disabled;"`), first thing I call back-end to get project data by the id which I get from clicked button (in this case ID=1), by which I know what project I'm updating.

When I need to update back end with new data and I do this first time in the newly loaded page, on click `$("#copy-btn").on('click', function(){` to send new data to the back-end, it works fine, sends only 1 `POST` request to the back-end and updates it correctly.

But, after closing (hiding) `Project 1` modal window `$('#project-modal').hide();` and opening another `Project 2` modal window and sending an update `$("#copy-btn").on('click', function(){` to the back-end with `ID=2` for some kind of a reason with this I send it 2 requests. 1st request with `ID=2` and 2nd request with `ID=2`.

How can I handle multiple modal window openings without sending multiple requests with previously opened modal window generated `ID`?

Should I create modal window on the fly and not hide it, but destroy/remove it?
Or the JavaScript code of mine is incorrect and how to improve it?
Or I'm doing at all in a wrong way?

If you need more information on this, please ask, I will update the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because on each button click opening a modal window like:

```
$(".modal-button").on('click', function () {
```

You are adding a new event listener for `$("#copy-btn")` each time like:

```
$("#copy-btn").on('click', function(){
```

So, to resolve this issue you simply need to remove all previous event handlers that were attached with [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) using the [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) method like:

```
$("#copy-btn").off('click').on('click', function(){
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed my issue. Thank you sir!